# Any component like "Reply to post/blog" in SenchaTouch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, javascript, sencha-touch-2

Is there any component like reply to post/blog in sencha touch 2 for giving any reply?
(for clearing question: component like, if we click to reply button then it will show box with subject and data etc)

Comment: I thnk that you have to develop it yourself, unless there is a plugin for that, but not built in the framework...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement it yourself, but it wouldn't be too difficult.

You would simply create a view which has a [textareafield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.TextArea) in it. You would show this view when you tap on a button, and then call [field.setValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Field-method-setValue) with the predefined value you want to add.